# Groovy set properties with token number in loop.

Tags: groovy, soapui

in the following example we are executing 5 times a request with different input data.
is it possible in the same time to save the token number of each request and set in property, for example
 token1 = token from request1
 token2 = token from request2

here is the groovy code:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def MAX_LIMIT = 2

    def countries = new Object[MAX_LIMIT]
    countries[0] = "India"
    countries[1] = "US"

    // Invoke Method
    GetCountries(countries);

    // Method Definition
    void GetCountries(Object[] countries)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
        {
            // Assign values to the global properties and call the servive
  com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties.setPropertyValue("CountryName", countries[i] )

            // Call GetCitiesByCountry service to run
            def testStep=testRunner.testCase.testSteps['GetCities'];
            testStep.run(testRunner,context);           
        }
    }
```

and my groovy to save token for one request is:

```
def response = context.expand( '${GetCities#Response#declare namespace ns1=\'https://info.io/ns/20140618\'; //ns1:GetCities_resp[1]/ns1:item[1]/ns1:response[1]}' )
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def result = slurper.parseText(response)
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue ( "token", result.data.token )
```

Comment: can someone explain why i have -1 for my question, please

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I do not understand your question, but just change:

```
.setPropertyValue ( "token", result.data.token )
```

to:

```
.setPropertyValue ( "token" + i, result.data.token )
```